# What is on the stereo output of a mixer if I'm recording with only one mic?

Tags: electronics, mixing, mixer

I got a [small mixer](http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/zed-6fx/) and am using it for singing and applying some effects. I'm using a single microphone for recording. It's connected to an XLR to the mixer.

Given that I have a mono signal going into the mixer, and there is stereo signal coming out of the mixer (main out of the mixer are 2 XLRs) is it valid to assume that the stereo signals coming out of the mixer are the same?

Comment: You mean that the L and R channels are the same?

Comment: This might probably work better on [Sound Design.SE](http://sound.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Linuxios Yup, would that be a more understanding terminology? If so, I would change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to assume that L and R are basically the same (within the operating tolerances of the unit) if -

- The 'Pan' control for the channel is centred
- You're not using any of the stereo effects